# PHP inconsistency in logic operations

Tags: php, increment, logical-operators

```
$a = 0;
if($a == ++$a) // Evaluates to true
if($a > $a++) // Evaluates to true
```

The same code run in **c** evaluates to false.

How is this possible?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php might help. `++` has a higher precedence over `==`, but you're also comparing the same variable on either side. This can lead to unexpected results.

Comment: `++$a` increments the value of $a by one, and then “returns” the new value into that position of the expression. `$a == ++$a` – so `++$a` makes it 1, and then afterwards this gets compared to the _current_ value of $a, which _is_ 1 at that point already. `$a++` works the other way around - the current value of $a is returned into the expression, only after that does $a get incremented - so with the second one, you effectively have `1 > 0` here.

Comment: @04FS I'd put that as an answer^^ :)

Comment: You should never trust these operations in comparison checks. This is language implementation dependant.

Comment: why is this question down voted so badly - it's actually pretty interesting, or so I think. The first if condition makes sense(`true`, `1==1`), but I still can't wrap my head around the second if condition returning `true`...

Comment: _$a++ works the other way around - the current value of $a is returned into the expression, only after that does $a get incremented_ - so wouldn't that mean that the expression would be `1 > 1`?

Comment: @waterloomatt if you take this apart piece by piece and go through them step by step, then `$a > $a++` “becomes” `$a > 0` first, _then_ $a gets incremented, and then the first $a is replaced with the _current_ value, so you end up with effectively `1 > 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`++$a` increments the value of `$a` by one, and then “returns” the new value into that position of the expression.
`$a == ++$a` – so `++$a` makes it `1`, and then afterwards this gets compared to the *current* value of `$a`, which *is* `1` at that point already.

`$a++` works the other way around - the current value of $a is returned into the expression, only after that does `$a` get incremented - so with the second one, you effectively have `1 > 0` here.
(With `$a > ++$a` instead `$a` would get incremented first, so that would be `1 > 1` effectively, resulting in `false`.)

Comment: Um... so..., when we exit the first `if` condition _$a is `1` at that point_, then going into the second `if` condition how can we _effectively have `1 > 0`? Shouldn't it _effectively_ "read" `1 > 1++` with `$a` ending-up (being post-incremented) to `2`?

Comment: @jibsteroos I was answering for a case where $a was reset to 0 between the two :-) But if not, then the whole thing just get “shifted“ by 1 for the second if, yes - you start with 1, then $a++ gets _post_-incremented to 2, so the effective condition is eventually 2 > 1.